# UITableView inside of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `tableView` of music albums.  For each `cell` of `tableView` I'd like to display the music album cover art and also the list of music tracks of the corresponding album.

So basically, in each music albums **`UITableViewCell` there will be the music album cover art on the top half, and a `UITableView` on the bottom half.**

`UITableViewCell` example:

[image]

I'm as far as adding the music album cover art on the top half, and a blank `UITableView` on the bottom half.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AlbumsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    MPMediaItem *rowItem = [[albumsArrayForTVC objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] representativeItem];
    MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [rowItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    inputImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (1024, 1024)];
    if (inputImage) {
        cell.backgroundImageView.image = inputImage;
    } else {
        cell.backgroundImageView.image = nil;
    }

    UITableViewCell *songCell = [cell.songTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OtherCell"];
    songCell.textLabel.text = @"This text doesn't show up yet";
    return cell;
}
```

I can't figure out inside `cellForIndexPath` how to fill in the `UITableView` of songs. I'm just trying to use a static `textLabel.text` right now, even though I'll eventually fill it in via the actual `NSArray` of songs.

I know this is a confusing thing to do, and stylistically it wouldn't make sense in most cases, but is there anyone that knows how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use sections. Each section header should display album cover and each cell in section should display the song name. Don't add a table view inside cell view...

in `numberOfSections` method return the number of albums, inside the `viewForHeaderInSection` add album cover, and in `cellForRow...` check which section is and display song name....

Comment: Cool I will try this!